# Can notification.setSound() be used with multiple audio sources?

Tags: java, android

**Expected:** A different audio file plays for each if statement

**Actual:** The first audio file plays for all notifications. The text message updates correctly, so it is meeting the if statement requirements.

Is there a way to have the correct audio file play?

```
if (alarm.getMINS().equals("0")) {
  alarmSound = audioAlert;
  text = context.getString(R.string.message);

} else if (alarmn.getMINS().equals("2")) {
  alarmSound = audioReminder;
  text = context.getString(R.string.reminder);

} else if (alarm.getMINS().equals("5")) {
  alarmSound = audioImportant;
  text = context.getString(R.string.important);
}

notification.setSound(alarmSound, audioAttributes);

...

  .setContentText(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound on a per-`Notification` basis has been deprecated since Android 5.0. Sounds are now set on the notification channel, and each channel has one sound.